# rsync --compare-dest

Tags: rsync

Tengo estas carpetas  SRC , DST, COMPARE:

**1. /opt/SRC**

- file1
- file2
- file3

**2. /opt/DST**

- file1
- file2

**3. /opt/COMPARE**

- vacío

Deseo que al ejecutar rsync los archivos que no existan en DST se almacenen en ***/opt/COMPARE.***

Es decir:

**ls /opt/COMPARE
f3**

Pero al ejecutar:

```
rsync -avz --compare-dest=/opt/COMPARE /opt/SRC/ /opt/DST
```

La carpeta **/opt/COMPARE** sigue vacía , ¿por qué?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que sucede que lo estas entendio de forma erronea
**explico:**

```
rsync origen/ destino/
```

el flag `--compare-dest=comparar/` sirve para asignar una carperta con la que se compare `origen`

ahora bien el comando deberia quedar.

```
rsync -avz --compare-dest=/opt/DST/ /opt/SRC/ /opt/COMPARE
```

para que se compare `origen` con `destino` y copie los cambios a `/opt/COMPARE`

> **nota:** agregar `/opt/SRC/` con `/` al final es decirle que agrege lo que esta dentro del directorio `/opt/SRC/` mientras que `/opt/SRC` es copiar el directorio `/opt/SRC`

Comment: ya lo verifique excelente!  , como valoro tu respuesta y cierro el tema

Comment: dandole al check o gancho que te aparese en la esquina superior derecha debajo del `0`